# How to do styling for the <select> <option> using jquery or css?

Tags: jquery, css

How to do styling for option html tag ?

```
 <option> using jquery or css?
```

Comment: tried `select option { /*css code*/ }`..?? but NOTE you can not make it work in IE...

Comment: Please consider searching first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: Someone upvoted this? Why?!

Answer (score 4):

You might need to take a look at the jQuery plugin  **[`jqtransform`](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)**.

I have personally tested it and its works in `IE-7`.

Answer (score 2):

Very low quality question.. but here goes..

you can style it in an external CSS by using :

```
option {color:green;}
```

you can use inline-styling like this :

```
<option style="color:green;">
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and tell that there are some few styling options available using this way.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy let the questioner edit his question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the links for a great css and jQuery for the select option tag:

[tyle-select-box-using-only-css](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/).
[custom-styling-of-the-select-elements](http://cssglobe.com/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements/).
[harvesthq.github](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Hope these links will help you.

Comment: Please elaborate on the name/site since now we have to click to see we already know the site

Answer (score 1):

Hi try with these links

```
http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/
http://cssdeck.com/item/265/styling-select-box-with-css3
http://cssglobe.com/post/8802/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements
```

or you can go with jquery plugins like

```
http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-create-nice-looking-dropdowns-using-dropkick-js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery chosen library to style select box

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/